# How to determine the number of existing derivatives?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let's say I have a function: $$f:V\to V'$$To check if this function has derivative at $a\in V$ one can simply use the definition of derivative to see if the limit exists.

Is there a way to check if, for a given $m$, $f\in C^m(V)$ without checking if the derivative exists $m$ times?

If no for a general $m$, maybe there are special cases? Like checking if a function is smooth.

Comment: How is the function given to you?

Comment: @RobArthan I'm hoping for a general case solution if exists one. Or at least a method to approach any given function

Answer (score 0):

There are classes of functions which are differentiable infinitely many times.

Polynomials, such as$$ P(x)= a_0+ a_1x+a_2x^2+...a_nx^n $$

Exponentials such as $e^{kx}, e^{P(x)}$,where $P(x)$ is a polynomial.

Some trig functions such as $$\sin (kx), \cos (kx) $$

Product or composition of the above functions are also differentiable infinitely many times.

For functions which are not well known to be differentiable we have to check them out. 
for example $f(x) = \sqrt x$ is not differentiable at $ x=0$ so its higher derivatives do not exist at that point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know that there are classes we know how they are smooth. If I was given a function that is not a part of those classes, can I check how many derivatives exists without taking the derivative?

Comment: I do not have an answer for that. I do not think it is possible to determine right away without  taking derivatives.